# How to implement a silent ID token renew in Blazor Server Side App connected to Azure AD B2C?

Tags: token, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, auto-renewing

I have an Blazor Server Side App with Azure AD B2C authentication using authorization code flow. On user login the app successfully retrieves an ID token, an access token and a refresh token for the user. All tokens are stored in the authorization cookie.

Currently the app validates the ID token periodically in `ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync` of a customized `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider`. The provider gets the `exp` claim and validates whether the token has been expired or not. In case of expiration the provider simply returns `Task.FromResult(false);` which results in the user being logged out.

Instead of a user sign-off I would rather implement a silent renew / refresh of the ID token. I've tried existing solutions (hidden iframe with some HTTP requests) like `oidc-client` but here the first request to the `/authorize` endpoint uses `prompt=none` which is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) by B2C (login page is always displayed in the hidden iframe).

How to do this without implementing everything from scratch? Is there an existing solution I can use?

Answer (score 1):

When using Authorization Code flow with Azure AD B2C, the refresh token should be sent to the `/token` endpoint (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#endpoints). The library you are using should be doing it automatically or you have to do it using a call to `/token` endpoint like the following:

```
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6&scope=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 offline_access&refresh_token=<<REFRESH-TOKEN>>
```

Comment: how about getting token silently in blazor client side, especially for blazor PWA? I am using MSAL library.